what is the minimum age for a girl to be considered a concubine?
I mean, is there a minimum age limit for a girl captured to be considered specifically a concubine to have relations with?

There is no minimum age. The master can have relations with her whenever she is able to have them without suffering injury, similar to the case of a wife.
